# Want to remove one of the two version of python installed on my machine

Tags: installation, python-3.5, python-3.6, uninstallation

I have both the versions of python 3.5.2 and python 3.6.3, but I want to remove the 3.6.3 version (as all the dependencies are installed in 3.5.2) and then upgrade the 3.5.2 version to the latest one.
Please suggest a way to do so without damaging the OS(I am using Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

## Some steps:

Open Control Panel.
Click "Uninstall a Program."
Scroll down to Python and click uninstall for each version you don't want anymore.

This works on Windows 7, no additional programs or scripts required. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.3, sorry didn't mention in the question